# Add content after a number of entries, continue entries

Tags: php, counter

Can someone translate this code into pure php for me.

```
{assign var="counter" value="0"}  
{$counter=0}
 {foreach from=$entries item=entry}
  {math equation="x + 1" x=$counter assign="counter"}

  <div class="entry">...</div>

  {if $counter==6}

  <div class="content">...</div>

  {/if}
 {/foreach}
```

Thank you a lot, sorry for my php illiteracy.

edit:
The $counter counts how many entries (in this case images from a database) are listed and after a certain number it displays some outside content (eg: advertisement) then the entries continue to be listed from where they left of.

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = 1;
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo '<div class="entry">...</div>';

    // If the counter value is divisible by 6, then output the extra content.
    // Increment the counter afterwards
    if ($counter++ % 6 == 0) {
        echo '<div class="content">...</div>';
    }
}
```

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, so there is my interpretation of it.

Comment: The $counter counts how many entries (in this case images from a database) are listed and after a certain number it displays some outside content (eg: advertisement) then the entries continue to be listed from where they left of.

Comment: If you want the outside content to be displayed after every 6 elements, that's different. I'll edit the code accordingly.